# How to run full vacuum on multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I need a help related to running full vacuum on multiple tables.

We are using postgreSQL-11, there are a couple of tables that are bloated with 20GB or larger, and running a full vacuum on them takes more than 15 minutes, and doing each table one after another sequentially takes more time to complete the full vacuum.

Is it possible to run full vacuum on multiple tables in parallel?

**Many Thanks,
Suresh.**

Comment: does this fix your problem: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303052/use-pg-cron-to-run-vacuum-on-multiple-tables @Suresh

Comment: Thank you @Dolphin, but this runs sequentially, it's not parallel execution

Comment: Sure, but you need to open one connection for each parallel job. Use your favorite shell to script it.  And fix whatever problem is making this necessary.